How do I do a SQL Left Join that first tries to match on one column, but then matches on a different column if first match fails?

Output that I'd like:

How do I pull in all the people from Favorite Foods table (table 1), and match them up with their Email/Phone number from Table 2 using a name match, and if that doesn't work, then look up their ID to then pull in the email/phone?
In Excel, the problem is solved by doing a couple VLOOKUPS wrapped in "IFNA" to try one Vlookup on Name matching, and if it fails, then doing a VLookup on the ID. Between the two, I can match up just about all of the data. My data sets are far too large for Excel.
My psuedo-code attempt / thought process:
select * from People 
LEFT JOIN Contacts ON People.Name == Contacts.Name, 
if Null, then LEFT JOIN Contacts ON People.ID == Contacts.ID


Please provide data as tables with text, not as image, because people can't copy it to try out possible solutions.

How come some ID values are missing? I'd assume those to be mandatory (NOT NULL).

@jarlh Why do you think that's homework? Note they did show what they have tried (at the end of their question). I still think it would be more useful/important to provide the data as text and/or trough a fiddle.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question?

You need INNER JOIN and simple OR logic.
This query succeeds on this sample fiddle and produces the expected result:
SELECT
    p.Name,
    p.Id,
    p.favorite_food,
    c.email,
    c.phone
FROM
    people p
    INNER JOIN contacts c
        ON p.name = c.name 
           OR p.id = c.id;

As the fiddle proves, it fetches the rows for both cases (names match or ids match), but does not duplicate them in the result. Rows that don't match will be excluded.
Sample input data used in the fiddle:
Table people:



name
id
favorite_food




John Smith
4583
Spaghetti


Jake Olson
null
Fruit


Matt Test
null
Cookies


Not found
-1000
Orange


Id Match
100
Apple


Double match
1
1



Table contacts:



name
id
email
phone




John Smith
null
mail1
phone1


Jake Olson
8888
mail2
phone2


Matt Test
null
mail3
phone3


Id found
100
mail4
phone4


Double match
1
mail5
phone5



Result:



name
id
favorite_food
email
phone




John Smith
4583
Spaghetti
mail1
phone1


Jake Olson
null
Fruit
mail2
phone2


Matt Test
null
Cookies
mail3
phone3


Id Match
100
Apple
mail4
phone4


Double match
1
1
mail5
phone5



The first three people in the result match by name, the fourth by id, the last by both name and id. The person "Not found" doesn't match and  therefore doesn't appear in the result.

You may left join from the people table to the contacts table twice, once for each potential match to either name or ID:
SELECT
    p.Name,
    p.ID,
    p.favorite_food,
    COALESCE(c1.email, c2.email) AS email,
    COALESCE(c1.phone, c2.phone) AS phone
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN contacts c1
    ON c1.Name = p.Name
LEFT JOIN contacts c2
    ON c2.ID = p.ID;


How can NULL id on both sides possibly match using an equality comparison?

I must extend my previous comment: Your query will return all rows, even if neither name nor id match and even if you extend both on clauses by and 1=2, see this sample fiddle

this query is working with any data sample
select 
   g.*,h.email,h.PhoneNumber 
from People g 
left join  
    (select * 
    from
        (select a.*,b.Email,b.PhoneNumber 
        from People a 
        inner join Contact b
        on a.Name=b.Name) e
    union
    select * 
    from
        (select c.*,d.Email,d.PhoneNumber 
        from People c 
        inner join Contact d
        on c.ID=d.ID) f ) h
    on g.Name=h.Name


Can you add some explanation to your answer?  (see, about code-only-answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390313/code-only-answers )

SELECT p.Name, p.Id, p.Food, c.Email, c.Phone
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN contacts c
ON (p.Name = c.Name OR p.Id = c.Id)
GROUP BY p.Food Order By p.Food;


No, after replacing p.Food for p.favorite_Food, still an error, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/CqxPhQIu   (and the formartting of you answer is incorrect!
